# Finding round figure

Tags: python

In Python, if I have a list with float numbers, how can I find all entries, which are round figures?

e.g. 
Checking x=[1.234,0.000000,2.0,0.0001] gives output

```
  >>>     False
          True
          True
          False
```

I tried isinstance function, which did not worked :

```
x=[1.234,0.000000,2.0,0.0001]
for i in x:
    print(isinstance(i, int))
```

I guess technically 2.0 and such are not of type integers. So I can not use it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `isinstance` does not work, as those are technically still all `float`:

```
>>> x = [1.234, 0.000000, 2.0, 0.0001]
>>> [type(n) for n in x]
[float, float, float, float]
```

But you can check whether the value, converted to an `int`, is equal to the original value:

```
>>> [n == int(n) for n in x]
[False, True, True, False]
```

Or, as pointed out in comments, using `float.is_integer`:

```
>>> [n.is_integer() for n in x]
[False, True, True, False]
```

Comment: Why not just use `float.is_integer()` then?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Because I did not think of it. ;-) Added to answer.

Comment: Since these are floats and floats are always approximations, what about `(4**3) ** (1.0/3)` (the cube root of the cube of 4)? That's not *quite* 4, that's  3.9999999999999996. Is that close enough to a whole number?